# how to translate "not A unless P or Q"

Tags: logic

As the title mentions, I am not sure how to translate the quote-unquote. Could anyone help explain how to translate "not $A$ unless $P$ or $Q$" correctly?

Comment: Unfortunately, I feel I had to flag this. This isn’t a site that will solve problems **for** you, and some effort or examples of your own thoughts must be shown. That way, we can help you—and others—the best we can. For more information, please read [how to ask a good question](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ). At any rate, I wish the best of luck to you, and please continue to contribute to our wonderful site!

Comment: https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/32366/if-p-then-q-q-unless-p  In particular, the linked answer gives a citation: [Stephen Cole Kleene, Mathematical logic (1967 - Dover ed 2002), page 64.](https://books.google.it/books?id=q-YEuuZ_j8EC&pg=PA64#v=onepage&q&f=false)

Comment: $P\vee Q\Longrightarrow \neg A$

Answer (score 1):

To write the expression in symbolic form, you need to find a synonymous expression in English which contains only words that can be represented by the symbols you have available.   "Not A unless P or Q" is synonymous with "A implies P or Q".   Do you know how to express this latter statement symbollically?

**Correction:** Thanks to [JMoravitz](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/179297/jmoravitz) for pointing out that I originally had the implication the wrong way round.

Comment: I'm not found with an umbrella unless rain is forecasted.  There can certainly be rain forecasted and me forget my umbrella though.  I disagree with $(P\vee Q)\implies A$.  Instead I read this as $A\implies (P\vee Q)$